# We are unable to complete your request at this time. Paypal

Tags: facebook, paypal

So I am trying to link my paypal account with my fb ads account and i always get this error.. any idea what to do?

Check image here: https://i.gyazo.com/1875d81562ca370431b40a8ff98cd79d.png

Comment: do you find any thing to solve this issue? I just get same error too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they link by granting 3rd party API permissions in PayPal. Log in to your PayPal account and go to your profile, then my selling tools and then API access. Then go to edit 3rd party permissions and remove the permission granted to Facebook. Once you remove it, link the two again and that should resolve the issue.